# EclipseLink/JPA2 ManyToOne bidirectional cascade persist issue

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, one-to-many, ejb-3.1, bidirectional

This is similar to [How to cascade persist using JPA/EclipseLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197667/how-to-cascade-persist-using-jpa-eclipselink)

I have to entities like so. One is RoomEntity that has a one to many bi-directional relationship with ComputerEntity. eg. each room has 0..n computers.

```
@Entity
public class ComputerEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="computerSeq",strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @SequenceGenerator(name="computerSeq",sequenceName="SEQUENCECOMPUTERID",allocationSize=1)
    private long computerID;

    @Column(name = "COMPUTERID")
    public long getComputerID() {
        return computerID;
    }

    public void setComputerID(long computerID) {
        this.computerID = computerID;
    }

    private RoomEntity room;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOMID", referencedColumnName = "ROOMID")
    public RoomEntity getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(RoomEntity room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

} //ComputerEntity

@Entity
public class RoomEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="roomSeq",strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="roomSeq",sequenceName="SEQUENCEROOMID",allocationSize=1)
    private long roomID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private Set<ComputerEntity> computers;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "ROOMID")
    public long getRoomID() {
        return roomID;
    }

    public void setRoomID(long roomID) {
        this.roomID = roomID;
    }

    public Set<ComputerEntity> getComputers() {
        return computers;
    }

    public void setComputers(Set<ComputerEntity> computers) {
        for(ComputerEntity computer : computers) {
            computer.setRoom(this);
        }
        this.computers = computers;
    }
}//RoomEntity
```

When I try to persist an new room with a computer like so:

```
    RoomEntity room = new RoomEntity();
    room.setAdministrator("Fox Moulder");
    room.setLocation("Area 51");

    ComputerEntity computer1 = new ComputerEntity();
    computer1.setDescription("Alienware area51 laptop");
    Set<ComputerEntity> computers = new HashSet<ComputerEntity>();
    computers.add(computer1);

    room.setComputers(computers);

    roomBean.createRoom(room);
```

roomBean is a Stateless EJB and roomBean.createRoom simply calls entityManager.persist(room). Since I have a CascadeType.PERSIST on the computers field of RoomEntity the ComptuerEntity is created. However, if I look at the room field of that ComputerEntity I see that room field is null. I would have assumed that Eclipselink would have automatically filled in the room since I have a bi-directional relationship. In order to have the room set in this way I had to add

```
        for(ComputerEntity computer : computers) {
            computer.setRoom(this);
        }
```

to room.setComputers(...). Is this the correct approach or is there a way to get Eclipselink to automatically set this?

Thanks.
-Noah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship maintenance in JPA.  EJB 2.1 has shown that generic relationship management is for too inefficient and cumbersome.

I recommend adding an addComputer() method that would set the RoomEntity on the newly added ComputerEntity